# WPF window width and height not displaying as expected

Tags: c#, wpf

If I make 2 rectangles and one has a height of 1000, the other one has a height of 1080 and my window height is/should be 1080, so the expected result is that i see one bar, 1000px high, and another one 1080 px high. But when i run the appication is see 2 bar of the same height extend all the way to the bottom of the screen. Its like the window size is too big. (i know for sure my monitor is at 1920 by 1080). This is probably some stupid beginner mistake, but i have not been able to find the awnser.

```
<Window x:Class="LIBRA.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Height="1080" Width="1920" 
    WindowStyle="None" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" 
    WindowState="Maximized">

  <Grid Background="#FF00796B" >  
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="1000"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"  Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top" />      
    <Rectangle Fill="#FF181878"  Height="1080"
       Margin="0,0,0,0"   Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

( i cant post images yet unfortunalty)

Comment: Sorks for me.  Take the size down.

Comment: Looking at your xaml, I'm wondering if this is the exact copy of your xaml File.. You should NOT be able to see the first (gray) rectangle at all because it _is_ **behind/below** the secund (blue) one wich is larger in height. Also, if you use `WindowState="Maximized"`, then delete the `Height` and `Width` of the Window. Otherwise, I don't have the answer. What I wrote is what _I expect to see_, looking at the xaml code : one unique blue vertical bar/rectangle on the left filling the entire height on a green background (Grid).

Comment: the gray one is a bit wider than the blue one. And deleting the height and width didnt help, it didnt change anything.(visualy) thanks for taking the time.

Comment: You're right. Didn't see the difference in width, just in height. (The height and width deletion was not meant to fix something, just to remove some not required properties)

Comment: I don't have the answer. Just copied and ran your code, I see one blue rectangle on the left filling the whole height of the screen, and next to it, a light gray thin vertical bar _not_ filling the whole screen height. :/ Could be some zoom factor on your machine or other display settings ? (test : make a printscreen, then paste the bitmap in a graphical editor, then measure the pixels. If the width is above or below 100 for the blue rectangle, then you have some display scaling override)

Comment: The printscreen is a perfect 1920 by 1080, but with 2 bars of the same lenght. Its really weird, i mean this is not complicated code, i will continue to try and fix this tommorow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm on a laptop and I use my dedicated graphics card for everything. If i run the application on my integrated graphics card the problem is solved.

So if you are having a similar problem try and disable your dedicated graphics card.